# Python: recursive isinstance checking

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-3.5, type-hinting

How can one check a complete type signature of a nested abstract class? In this example

```
In [4]: from typing import Sequence

In [5]: IntSeq = Sequence[int]

In [6]: isinstance([1], IntSeq)
Out[6]: True

In [7]: isinstance([1.0], IntSeq)
Out[7]: True
```

I want the last `isinstance` call to actually return `False`, while it only checks that the argument is a `Sequence`. I thought about recursively checking the types, but `IntSeq` has no public attributes that store the nested type(s):

```
In [8]: dir(IntSeq)
Out[8]: 
['__abstractmethods__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__extra__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__origin__',
 '__parameters__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__slots__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_abc_cache',
 '_abc_negative_cache',
 '_abc_negative_cache_version',
 '_abc_registry']
```

So it doesn't seem to be straightforward to get nested types. I can't find relevant information in the docs.

P.S.
I need this for a multiple dispatch implementation.

**Update**

Thanks to the feedback from Alexander Huszagh and Blender we now know that abstract classes in Python 3.5 (might) have two attributes that store the nested types: `__parameters__` and `__args__`. The former is there under both Linux (Ubuntu) and Darwin (OS X), though it is empty in case of Linux. The later is only available under Linux and stores the types like `__parameters__` does under OS X. This implementation details add up to the confusion.

Comment: I'd like the close-voter to explain his choice of "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs".

Comment: `isinstance(["hello"], int_seq)` is also `True`. Are you sure you are not creating a bigger problem than solving when trying to use typing instead of simple type check?

Comment: @DmitryTorba I'm trying to implement true multiple dispatch in Python, so I need the dispatcher to be able to check the complete type signature.

Comment: @blender helped me find the answer to find the type of the sequence:
`Sequence[int].__args__`. `Sequence[int].__parameters__` seems to be implementation specific. You can apply his now deleted answer to the same workflow.

Comment: @EliKorvigo interesting. Let me test with other installs. There may be no good answer then....

Just an FYI, that works with Python 3.5.2, Ubuntu, GCC 5.4.0.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Do you mean that the availability of either of these attributes depends on Python version or a particular abstract type implementation? `Sequence` has no `__args__` attribute on Python 3.5.1 on my system (Darwin).

Comment: You may find this module useful: https://github.com/fabiommendes/pygeneric

Comment: EliKorvigo, likely. And @Blender seems to solve the XY problem directly. As typing is new in Python 3.5.x, it may be under heavy revision.

Comment: @Blender I'm already forking what seems to be a more feature-complete alternative https://github.com/mrocklin/multipledispatch . Anyway, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're trying to implement something using a module that is still provisional; you're bound to encounter a changing interface if you do this.

Blender noticed that the `__parameters__` argument holds the parameters to the type; this was true until, I believe `3.5.1`. In my git clone of the most recent version of Python (`3.6.0a4+`) `__parameters__` again holds an empty tuple, `__args__` holds the argument and `__origin__` is the first entry in its `__bases__` attribute:

```
>>> intSeq = typing.Sequence[int]
>>> intSeq.__args__
(<class 'int'>,)
>>> intSeq.__parameters__
()
>>> intSeq.__origin__
typing.Sequence<+T_co>
```

Since `3.6` is when typing will, from what I understand from [`PEP 411`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0411/), leave provisional and enter a stable state, this is the version you should be working with to implement your functionality.

Comment: Thank yo for the clarification. I've found no references to `typing` in PEP 411. Do you know what `+T_co` means in the `__origin__` attribute?

Comment: Yup, PEP 411 won't talk about which modules are provisional, that's in the abstract for [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#abstract) which introduced the module :-). `+T_co` means that the argument is covariant, you can read more about that in the same PEP (section [covariance and contravariance](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance)).